# Creating dynamic key names in Ruby hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm writing a small program that takes a word (or several words in an array) and a list of words (a "dictionary") as an input, and returns the number of times the inputted words are found in the dictionary.  The results have to show up in a hash.

In my code, I'm iterating through the inputted words and seeing if the dictionary `.include?`s the word.  I then add a key/value pair to my hash, with the key being the word that was found, and the value being incremented by one every time the word occurs in the dictionary.

I can't see any glaring issues in my code, but all I get as a result is an empty hash.  This particular example should return something like

```
{"sit" => 3,
"below" => 1}
```

Code:

```
dictionary = ["below","down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part","partner","sit", "sit", "sit"]

def Dictionary dictionary, *words
    word_count = Hash.new(0)
words.each{|word|
if dictionary.include?(word)
word_count[word] += 1
end
}
print word_count
end

Dictionary(dictionary, ["sit", "below"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove the splat operator (`*`) in the method definition:

```
def Dictionary(dictionary, words)
  word_count = Hash.new(0)
  words.each do |word|
    word_count[word] += 1 if dictionary.include?(word)
  end
  print word_count
end

Dictionary(dictionary, ["sit", "below"])
# {"sit"=>1, "below"=>1}
```

The reason is Ruby is wrapping the `words` argument within an array, which makes it be `[["sit", "below"]]` and when you iterate that, you get the value `["sit", "below"]` as the only element, and hence the condition returns false.

---

As stated by NullUserException, the result isn't as expected. To do so you need to swap the array of words that's being iterated:

```
...
dictionary.each do |word|
  word_count[word] += 1 if words.include?(word)
end
...
```

You could also take a look to the `each_with_object` method. It fits very well in this kind of cases:

```
dictionary.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word, hash|
  next unless words.include?(word)

  hash[word] += 1 
end
```

Comment: Woops, had that left over from before I used an array as the input.  Thanks!

Comment: I still don't think this does what the OP intended, because you aren't actually counting the instances of each word. I believe he wanted the output to be `{"sit"=>1, "below"=>3}`

Comment: You're right @NullUserException. I've updated the answer, thanks for that!

Comment: Perhaps mention that method names are generally lowercase, and at the end, simplify to `hash[word] += 1 if words.include?(word)` and make `words` a set if the number of words to process is large.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the splat(*) operator, the words params will take all the parameters you pass to the method and convert it to an array,

That means, your `["sit", "below"]` is taken as the first element of an array and you get `[["sit", "below"]]` as words.

You can either:

1. remove the splat(*) operator so that the array is taken as it is, or
2. Change the arguments in the method call, i.e. `Dictionary(dictionary, "sit", "below")`

But, as you said in the question you want to be able to supply either a string or an array, I would go ahead with 1. and remove the splat operator

Also, you have messed up the order of the loop. You have to loop through your dictionary and count the instances of your words.

```
def Dictionary dictionary, words
    word_count = Hash.new(0)
    dictionary.each{ |word|
        if words.include?(word)
            word_count[word] += 1
        end
    }
    print word_count
end
```

This should fix it